# BroadCastReceiver is called several times

Tags: android, kotlin, broadcastreceiver

I have the problem that the messages within my GpsLocationReceiver class appear several times after I have switched the location on and off.
I use dynamic intent filters

```
val receiver: BroadcastReceiver = GpsLocationReceiver()


override fun onPause() {
    super.onPause()
    unregisterReceiver(receiver)
}


override fun onResume() {
    super.onResume()
    IntentFilter("android.location.PROVIDERS_CHANGED").also {
        registerReceiver(receiver,it)
    }

}
```

GpsLocationReceiver.tk:

```
 class GpsLocationReceiver: BroadcastReceiver() {

 override fun onReceive(context: Context?, intent: Intent?) {


     var gpsModeEnabled = intent?.getBooleanExtra("state",false) ?: return

     if(gpsModeEnabled)
     {
         Toast.makeText(
             context, "GPS IS ON",
             Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
         ).show()
     }
     else{
         Toast.makeText(
             context, "GPS IS OFF",
             Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
         ).show()
     }


  }
```

}